# How can I detect multiple mouse clicks?

Tags: p5.js

A complete noob here. I'm trying to simulate an old phone keyboard, when there were physical buttons that were grouped like ABC, DEF, ..., PQRS, etc, and you could click a button once for the first letter, twice for the second and so on.
I know about the existence of mousePressed() and doubleCliked() functions, but is there a way to detect triple and quadruple clicks?

Comment: Those phones didn't actually really detect double/triple/quadruple clicks. If you press "1" once, it types an A. If you press "1" again in a short period of time, it changes that A into a B. And so on. I would recommend that you use that sort of logic. (Or at least, that's how I would approach it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you are describing is to have variables that store which button was pressed last, how many times it has been pressed in a row, and what time it was pressed. Then you can determine whether or not to increment the count if the same button is pressed again in a particular window of time.

```js
let twoBtn;
let threeBtn;
let strTxt;

let lastPressed;
let lastPressTime;
let lastPressCount;

let letters = [[], [], ['A', 'B', 'C', '2'], ['D', 'E', 'F', '3']];

let value = '';
let next = '';

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    
    twoBtn = createButton('2 (ABC)');
    twoBtn.mouseClicked(() => {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastPressed === 2 && (now - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
            lastPressedCount++;
            next = letters[2][lastPressedCount - 1];
        } else {
            value += next;
            next = 'A';
            lastPressed = 2;
            lastPressedCount = 1;
        }
        lastPressTime = now;
        strTxt.value(value + next);
    });
    
    threeBtn = createButton('3 (DEF)');
    threeBtn.mouseClicked(() => {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastPressed === 3 && (now - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
            lastPressedCount++;
            next = letters[3][lastPressedCount - 1];
        } else {
            value += next;
            next = 'D';
            lastPressed = 3;
            lastPressedCount = 1;
        }
        lastPressTime = now;
        strTxt.value(value + next);
    });
    
    strTxt = createInput();
    strTxt.attribute('readonly', 'readonly');
}

function draw() {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I could have just used `millis()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`. I don't know why I forgot about that.